# Spark: Read CSV file with headers

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a CSV file with 90 columns and around 28000 rows.

I want to load it and split it in train (75%) and test (25%). I used the following code:

Code:

```
val data = sc.textFile(datadir + "/dados_frontwave_corte_pedra_ferramenta.csv")
        .map(line => line.split(","))
            .filter(line => line.length>1)
        .collect();

// Building the model
val numIterations = 20;
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(data, numIterations);
```

I get the following error on the "data":

```
type mismatch; found : Array[Array[String]] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
```

What is the problem? I search it on the internet and I couldn't find any clear answer.

I found this [Spark Example](https://altiscale.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202627136-Spark-Shell-Examples) and change my code as follow:

```
val data = sc.textFile(datadir + "/dados_frontwave_corte_pedra_ferramenta.csv")
val parsedData = data.map {line =>
    val parts = line.split(",")
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(",").map(x => x.toDouble).toArray))
    };
```

The error has gone but when I run the code the following error is produced:

```
15/04/15 16:53:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string ""12316""
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLinke$class.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
....
```

Sample of input file:

```
"","Ferramenta","Pedra","ensaio","Nrasgo","Vcorte","Vrotacional","PCorte","Tempo","Fh","Fr","Energia","Caudal","Vib_disco","Vib_maquina","xx","yy","zz","Fonte","id","rocha_classe","rocha_tipo","Resistência_mecânica_à_compressão","Res._mec._à_compr._após_teste_de_gelividade","Resistência_mecânica_à_flexão","Massa_volúmica_aparente","Absorção_de_água_à_P._At.N.","Porosidade_aberta","Coef._de_dilatação_linear_térmica_val._máx","Resistência_ao_desgaste","Resistência_ao_choque_altura_minima_de_queda","Resistência_ao_gelo","Al2O3","CaO","H2O.","K2O","MgO","MnO","Na2O","P2O5","SiO2","TiO2","microclina","plagioclase","quartzo","page_id","rocha_nome_2","P.R._.L.O.I..","plagioclase_.oligoclase.albite.","feldspato_potássico_.microclina.","feldspato_potássico_.essencialmente_microclina.","biotite","rocha_nome_3","oligoclase","plagioclase_.andesina.","horneblenda","feldspato_potássico","nefelina","aegirina_e_aegirina.augite","esfena","piroxena","olivina","horneblenda_verde","plagioclase_.oligoclase.","CO2","clorite","cloritóide","quartzo.feldspato","SO3","cloritóide.clorite","calcite","dolomite","serpentina_.antigorite.crisótilo.","mica_.biotite.moscovite.","feldspato","Fe2O3","plagioclase_ácida","cristobalite","rocha_nome_1","Ferramentas","Binder","LM","graf","WC","T","sigma","epsilon","m","E","H"
"1","A-010-13","estremoz","ECE-E1",5,26,1430,5,6.08,-0.0981,57,720,23.5,0.9,3.5,162,197.2,5,"ECE-A-010-13-Estremoz_1",2,"sedimentares ","calcário",960,767,276,2711,0.07,0.18,11.5,3.4,57.5,48,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"A-010/13","A-038/11","LM 156",0,0,800,425,0.0062,1.09,159,2085
"2","A-010-13","estremoz","ECE-E1",5,26,1430,5,5.9,-0.0981,63,720,23.5,0.9,3.5,157,197.2,5,"ECE-A-010-13-Estremoz_1",2,"sedimentares ","calcário",960,767,276,2711,0.07,0.18,11.5,3.4,57.5,48,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"A-010/13","A-038/11","LM 156",0,0,800,425,0.0062,1.09,159,2085
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at using spark-csv: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv, which does the parsing for you.

Comment: you  have double quotes along with your field, you'll need to trim that!! I would be nice if you give us a line or two of your input format

Comment: The first three lines of the input file are added to the question.

Comment: Like I said, you'll have to trim the double quote during the mapping phase. The first variable contains a double surrounded by double quotes so it will give you the error you produced

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the method `train` expects an RDD and you are passing it an Array.

`collect` is an action not a transformation. Removing the call to `collect` should fix your problem.

This should work

```
val data = sc.textFile(datadir + "/dados_frontwave_corte_pedra_ferramenta.csv")
             .map(line => line.split(","))
             .filter(line => line.length>1);

// Building the model
val numIterations = 20;
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(data, numIterations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a weird solution, but try this:

```
val parts = line.split(",").map(x => x.replace("\"", "")).filter(x => x.length > 0)
```

Comment: You mean: "val parts = line.split(",").map(x => x.replace("\"", ""))" instead of "val parts = line.split(",")"?

Comment: Exactly. You need to do something with those quotation marks.

Comment: I did. But the only change is the following line of errors: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: After adding the filter the error change to: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "Ferramenta"

Comment: Right, so LabeledPoint works with Double and "Ferramenta" is far away from that. LinearRegressionWithSGD.train works with LabeledPoint but your CSV contains numbers and strings as well. I don't know, what would you like to do exactly, but in terms of parsing a CSV my solution works.